# Ways to dry out space in wall or ceiling

Tags: ceiling, moisture

I am installing recessed lighting into our living room.

The ceiling of the room is topped with a flat roof.

At one point, there were a handful of leaks in this roof that have since been repaired. However, the space in the ceiling is damp.

I noticed this dampness after putting six inch holes into the ceiling for the recessed light cans.

What are some good ways to dry out these spaces?

I don't want to rip open the ceiling any further, if possible. I have six six-inch holes, plus ten 3-inch holes from where I opened the ceiling to pull wiring through the joists. (After also drilling holes in the joists, obviously)

I was considering throwing several pounds of Fresh Step Crystals, a silica-gel based cat litter, or just get bulk quantities of proper silica gel. I'm not sure how to easily inject the tiny sand-like pellets of silica gel into the ceiling, though. If there's a good way to shoot sand-sized pellets into a ceiling space, I'd love to hear it.

I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: You need to find source of damp. Else 6Lbs of kitty litter will just turn into 12 pounds of wet kitty litter.

Comment: source of damp *was* leaks in roof. the roof has been fixed though

Comment: Ventilated through the holes you've made then. Long term damp can lead to mold, which you do *not* want.